# Efficient method for computing the permutation group $G\subseteq S_{m}$ if $m$ is large .

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ such that $|S|=m$  be the set of all faces of some convex polyhedron and denote by $G$ all the rotational symmetries of the convex polyhedron. If we color the convex polyhedron using $r$ colors, two colorings of the convex polyhedron are said to be equivalent if we can get one from the other under some rotational symmetry in $G$. It is also well known that the number of equivalent classes are easily calculated using the formula. \begin{equation}\displaystyle{\frac{1}{G}\sum_{g\in G}r^{\alpha(g)}}\end{equation} where $\alpha(g)$ is the number of cycles in $g\in G\subseteq S_{m}$(**Cayley's theorem**).

If $|S|=m$ is small, e.g., tetrahedron, it's easy to compute the permutation group $G$, hence the number of equivalence classes shown above. However, for large values of $m$, computing the permutation group $G$ is difficult and time consuming.

**Question** What is easiest way or the best method of computing the permutation group $G\subseteq S_{m}$ if $m$ is large?

Comment: There aren't that many [finite spherical symmetry groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_spherical_symmetry_groups). It's not $G$ that becomes large or complicated when you have many faces on your symmetric polyhedron, its the $\alpha(g)$ that become large.

Comment: Jaap Scherphuis, I understand that there are 5 finite groups of rotations in $\mathbb{R^3}$. All I want is the subgroup of $S_{m}$ isomorphic to $G$ so that I may be able to compute $\alpha(g)$.